# How to convert string to date format in PHP?

Tags: php, html, date

I am trying to convert a date in string format to date format, here is the example

```
1. 15Oct15 to 2015-10-15
2. 151015  to 2015-10-15
3. 15102015 to 2015-10-15
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Have you googled convert string to php date? Cause I just have and the first hit was a question on here that perfectly outlines how to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: You could use a regex to determine which format you have, and then split it into pieces. Would you try writing some code? You may be able to do it on your own.

Comment: <?
$d1='15Oct15';
echo $d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d1)); => 2015-10-15

You have to change the format of $d2 & $d3 atleast like this.
Then, only you can expect the result.

$d2='15-10-15';
echo $d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d2)); => 2015-10-15

$d3='15-10-2015';
echo $d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d3)); => 2015-10-15

?>

Answer (score 0):

You can convert 
1. 15Oct15 to 2015-10-15
using 
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime("15Oct15"))`

Not sure of other 2