# How to convert datetime in string format into proper date & time format in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter-3

I got a JSON response of date and time in string format, and I want it to convert into proper date and time.
I'm using a API to get a response and that comes in JSON code, but while it is in string form. How can I convert it into Proper Date and Time.

I got following response:

```
"start_time": 1492841592,
"end_time": 1492841619,
"seconds": 22392,
"duration": "00:00:27",
"_drm": 0.45,
```

And I want output in :

```
01:10pm 16 Mar
```

This format.

To convert it I'm trying to use `date()` function from **PHP**. But it wont give me proper result.
I'm referred following question:

[How to convert string to date format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605570/how-to-convert-string-to-date-format-in-php)

[how to convert string day into date time format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349438/how-to-convert-string-day-into-date-time-format-in-php)

[how to convert String time to dateTime format in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126149/how-to-convert-string-time-to-datetime-format-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code looks like? What is the result you are gettin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```php
$json = <<<'JSON'
{
  "start_time": 1492841592,
  "end_time": 1492841619,
  "seconds": 22392,
  "duration": "00:00:27",
  "_drm": 0.45
}
JSON;

$dt = json_decode($json);

echo date('h:ia M j', $dt->start_time);
```

Output:

```
06:13am Apr 22
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/781343)